# How to identify AWS Outage on EC2 Instances without eye ball monitoring?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

If your application hosted on AWS and if there is any AWS Outage, How to detect the Outage early without eye ball monitoring. Any automation process or tool which we can use for the above ?

Comment: Amazon has an entire service just for this purpose: [CloudWatch](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/)

Comment: When you say "AWS Outage", are you referring to a problem with the software running on your Amazon EC2 instance, or are you referring to the Amazon EC2 service itself? AWS outages are extremely rare, but can be monitored via the [AWS Personal Health Dashboard](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/health/latest/ug/getting-started-phd.html).

Answer (score 0):

Amazon EC2 performs automated checks on every running EC2 instance to identify hardware and software issues. You can view the results of these status checks to identify specific and detectable problems or use the steps from the below document to set an alarm and get notified when an EC2 is down.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-system-instance-status-check.html#creating_status_check_alarms